# Getting output from Aruba OS using SSH

Tags: ssh, sshpass

I am using Aruba version 6.5.4.20 and from what I found it has no API and I need to use SSH and use Aruba's CLI. Basically what I want to do is get the number of connected clients at each Access Point and it works using this command: `show ap association ap-name <ap-name> | include "Num Clients"`. But I want to get the output of this command without need to ssh manually. I used sshpass using this command : `sshpass -p <password> username@hostname "show ap association ap-name <ap-name>"` but it returns nothing.

Any solution for this?